# Django 1.4: prefetch_related with custom model manager and order_by?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is a long shot question (doesn't seem like it is possible from the Django docs, but thought I'd ask just to see if anyone has any ideas).  Note: I'm using Django 1.4.

I want to use a custom model manager on a prefetch_related() query.  Then, on top of that, I want to order the prefetched results in a certain way.

To put it in simplified code, I have the following models (note: `Participant` model excluded from code because it is irrelevant):

```
class GoalParticipant(models.Model):
  """Many-to-many model between Goal and Participant models."""
  participant = models.ForeignKey(
      'Participant', related_name='goal_participants')
  goal = models.ForeignKey('Goal', related_name='goal_participants')
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Goal(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  progress = models.IntegerField()
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Milestone(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  progress = models.IntegerField()
  goal = models.ForeignKey('Goal', related_name='milestones')
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

From here, my page controller gets a `GoalParticipant` Id value (called, say, `pid`).  I want to display all of the goals and milestones for that ID.

So something like this would work normally:

```
GoalParticipant.objects.filter(participant=pid).select_related(
    ).prefetch_related('goal__milestones')
```

Here are the two wrinkles:

**1: Custom Model Manager**

All of my classes have custom model managers, like this:

```
  objects = ActiveManager()
  all_objects = models.Manager()
```

The `ActiveManager` runs `.filter(active=True)` on the queryset.  This is for convenience, so that I can easily just say `.objects` by default and have the active filter thrown in.  Occasionally, though, I need to display all of the objects, not just active ones.  So I tried this:

```
GoalParticipant.all_objects.filter(participant=pid).select_related(
    ).prefetch_related('goal__milestones')
```

This gives me all of the goal_participants and all of the goals, but still restricts to only active milestones.  Is there a way to force `prefetch_related` to use the `all_objects` model manager?

**2: Custom Ordering for Milestones**

Users can actually order the goals / milestones by either `name` or `progress` in the UI, and the ordering should be consistent. For example, if the goals are ordered by progress, the milestones should also be ordered by progress.  So, say I have a var called `ordering` with the correct ordering, I could do this:

```
GoalParticipant.objects.filter(participant=pid).select_related(
    ).order_by(ordering).prefetch_related('goal__milestones')
```

This orders the goals correctly, but there does not seem to be any way to force the milestones to order in the same way.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help and let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: FYI to anyone that ends up looking at this, seems like they are adding this to some future version of Django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17001.  Meanwhile, I just handled the custom queryset part by recreating a simplified version of prefetch_related's join logic for the special case I needed and handled the order_by part by just sorting in memory via python's sort.

Comment: I realize this is well after the fact but I wonder if you could post the source code you came up with as an answer? I'd like to see what your version of prefetch_related looks like.

Comment: I don't have the exact code anymore, but it wasn't anything too complicated.  I basically used django's `@functional.cached_property` decorator to make a property on `Participant` called `cached_goals`.  I queried for all of the goals for that participant using a separate query, then turned it into a list and set it to the `cached_goals` property (this is basically what `prefetch_related` does).  I did the same thing using another cached property on `Goal` called `cached_milestones`, with the only difference being that I sorted the list before setting it to the property.  Hope that helps.